# html5 video under image

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a video that is underneath a png image that has a transparent part for the video to show through.

```
<div id="Layer2" style="position:absolute; z-index:2; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 960px; height: 640px; visibility: visible">
<div align="left"><img src="http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/picture.png" width="960" height="640" /></div>
</div>
<div id="Layer1" style="position:absolute; z-index:1; left: 251px; top: 91px; width: 640px; height: 360px; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; ">
<div align="left" >[FMP poster="http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb.jpg" width="640" height="360"]http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/movie.webm[/FMP]</div>
</div>
```

How do I go about making the video clickable so people can access the video controls?

I have looked at CSS pointer-events:none property and this works but only in Firefox and Safari browsers. I know I can make my own video control buttons and place them above the image with a higher z-index but I would prefer to use the browsers native video controls. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what's the purpose of that image over the video? Should it be visible also during video playback?

Comment: Its just a design thing, some of the image over the video isn't transparent.

Comment: Could you position the image so that it's not blocking the controls of the media player?

Comment: its already like that, the video controls show through the transparent part of the png, only a bit of the left side and top of the video are covered by the actual image. The problem is that the controls, even though they can be seen, cannot be clicked on.

Comment: Oh and yes F. Calderan the image needs to be visible at all times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Support for the CSS3 pointer-events property](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) is pretty patchy.

To achieve what you want without having to re-implement the player controls I think you have two options:

1. Have a look at some of the available HTML5 video libraries. I'm certain one of these will allow you to style the controls to the level you require.
2. Break up your mask image into top, right, bottom and left slices and use these to frame your element, overlaying it if necessary. As long as none of the frame elements overlay the video controls you should be okay

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that isn't what i'm after as it is not exactly a border since the png image overlays part of the video.

Comment: In regards to what i'm after, imagine a black png image witha transparent box in the center. Now imagine a html5 <video> underneath that image which you can see a part of through the transparent part of the png. Now if you click on the transparent part I want to be able to access what is underneath, so if you can see the controls I want to be able to use them.

Comment: Okay, I don't think there's a way of doing this as the overlaid PNG will always block any interaction with elements below it. However, I think my original answer still stands (at least the part about implementing a frame for your video element using mark up). I'd suggest breaking up the image into top, right, bottom and left slices and use these to frame your element, overlaying them if necessary. As long as none of the frame elements overlay the video controls you should be okay.

Comment: Yes that was my next move but I was trying to avoid slicing the image. Like I said, pointer-events:none disables this behaviour in Firefox and Safari but not the other browsers as of yet which just blows. I would rather just be able to give the video controls a higher z-index than the png image so they can be used but I guess that is not possible, unless I make my own controls for the player.

Comment: Have a look at some of the available HTML5 video libraries. I'm almost certain one of these will give you the control over the styling of the controls you require to alter the z-index without requiring you to implement your own set of custom controls.

Comment: yep cool found a library with some controls I can z-index. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, did you mean to accept this answer?  I was actually in the process of deleting mine (just before you accepted it), since this one seemed to have a more comprehensive answer and suggested using a library, which mine did not.  I advise accept this answer instead of mine.

Comment: Thanks dude, that's really very sporting of you and much appreciated!

Comment: Yes I was torn between the two replies. Anyway I have done as you have asked. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your only option (aside from breaking up the image so it doesn't obstruct) is to make your own controls and place them over the transparent image.

```
<video controls="false" id="myVid">
    ...
</video>
...
<img src="play.png" id="playButton" onclick="togglePlay()" />
```

Where `togglePlay` is:

```
function togglePlay() {
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVid");
    var button = document.getElementById("playButton"); 
    if(vid.paused) {
        vid.play();
        playButton.src = "pause.png";
    } else {
        vid.pause();
        playButton.src = "play.png"; 
    }
}
```

You can style the buttons however you like, e.g., place them directly over your video, give them a higer z-index than your transparent image, make them disappear when you mouseout (or use a script that makes them disappear you mousemove outside certain x/y bounds), etc.

Comment: Thanks apsillers, I found a library with premade controls that I can z-index as net.uk.sweet suggested. Thanks for the code, I might make use of it at some stage.

Comment: Just curious, what library did you go with?